# What if I find someone else is using my Stack Exchange login?

Tags: support, hacked

I've just discovered an old Stack Exchange account of mine that seems to be in use by someone unknown to me (who has knowledge that doesn't fit anyone I know).

How do I delete that account?

Comment: Contact the team, it's mentioned in the more general discussion.